# Is there a difference between zones?

Tags: bit-city

When buying and zoning you have 3 options. Residential (Green), Business (Blue) and Service (some shade of Yellow). Is there a difference between them or could I just go all Residential?

Comment: Eventually the game will start asking you to complete quests where you need certain buildings and they only show up in certain zones. Also, the game does seem to want some balance, as it shows you the percentage of your city that is each type and how in demand they are when you are selecting what you want to fill a new block with. I didn't really play with that much, I tended to keep things pretty even,so I am not sure if the game punishes you in any way if it doesn't stay balanced

Answer (score 2):

The game expects you to provide a balanced city, with an even split of the three options. If you have too much or too little of one, it will effect the "demand" for that type.

For instance, you'll find that as you add more and more Residential, the demand for Residential will go down, starting with "Low Demand" and progressing downward. "Low Demand" and lower will penalize the income you get from those lots (the less demand, the bigger the penalty.

It goes the other way as well; if you have an option that's less covered, there will be "High Demand" and so on, and you get a bonus for those lots. However, from what I can tell, the bonus isn't really worth it compared to just having the lots built. It seems much better to keep things relatively balanced, if only because it's hard to have one type be "High Demand" and not eventually get one of the others to be "Low Demand". I've not done the math, though, for what it's worth.